# Testing for a Live Internet Connection in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Say the user has loaded a webpage in their browser from the hard drive, ie a 'file:' in the url. (Eg they might have created a microsoft mhtml file of my webpage.)

How can I check for a live internet connection?

[Edit: Someone can load an html file from their hard drive, but the page might still need a live connection for the page to function correctly.]

Comment: I don't think JS has any direct way to test this.

Comment: Someone can load an html file from their hard drive, but the page might still need a live connection for the page to function correctly.

Comment: @Barmar What exactly does a "live internet connection" mean?  I'd assume that what you really want to check for is connectivity to your application servers.  There are situations where you may be connected to the internet, but not have connectivity to everywhere.  I've had situations in cities where I could access certain sites but not others after regional networks had a fiber cut.  I've seen situations where IPv6 traffic worked fine, but IPv4 failed.  So, you need to more closely define what it is you expect to check for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading from a `file:` URL doesn't tell you anything about whether the user has a network connection.

If it's specifically the `file:` URL thing that worries you, look at [`document.location.protocol`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/protocol), which will be `file:` or `https:` or `http:`, etc.

If you want to know if there's a network connection, you can look at [`navigator.onLine`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/onLine) (see the link for caveats) or do a [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) to a known-good server.

Comment: `navigator.onLine` was what I am after. Will that change (on all browsers) if they turn on their internet after the page has loaded? Or is there on onchange event for this?

Comment: @Rewind The links you've been given have the information you're looking for.